# ApplicationData.LocalSettings not storing data?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm making an app where a use enters values for two times (starthour, startminute, endhour, endminute). I wrote a function that saves the values and then checks for value and puts the values inside the text boxes. However, it isn't working and I'm not sure why. I'm assuming its a mistake on my part, but I'm not exactly sure. Here's the code:

```
        public async Task savedata()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

            localSettings.Values["starthour1"] = starthour1.Text;
            localSettings.Values["starthour2"] = starthour2.Text;
            localSettings.Values["starthour3"] = starthour3.Text;
            localSettings.Values["starthour4"] = starthour4.Text;
            localSettings.Values["starthour5"] = starthour5.Text;
            localSettings.Values["starthour6"] = starthour6.Text;
            localSettings.Values["starthour7"] = starthour7.Text;

            localSettings.Values["startminute1"] = startminute1.Text;
            localSettings.Values["startminute2"] = startminute2.Text;
            localSettings.Values["startminute3"] = startminute3.Text;
            localSettings.Values["startminute4"] = startminute4.Text;
            localSettings.Values["startminute5"] = startminute5.Text;
            localSettings.Values["startminute6"] = startminute6.Text;
            localSettings.Values["startminute7"] = startminute7.Text;

            localSettings.Values["endhour1"] = endhour1.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endhour2"] = endhour2.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endhour3"] = endhour3.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endhour4"] = endhour4.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endhour5"] = endhour5.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endhour6"] = endhour6.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endhour7"] = endhour7.Text;

            localSettings.Values["endminute1"] = endminute1.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endminute2"] = endminute2.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endminute3"] = endminute3.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endminute4"] = endminute4.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endminute5"] = endminute5.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endminute6"] = endminute6.Text;
            localSettings.Values["endminute7"] = endminute7.Text;

            //get data
            Object starthour1o = localSettings.Values["starthour1"];

            if (starthour1o == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                starthour1.Text = starthour1o.ToString();
            }
            Object starthour2o = localSettings.Values["starthour2"];

            if (starthour2o == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                starthour2.Text = starthour2o.ToString();
            }
            Object starthour3o = localSettings.Values["starthour3"];

            if (starthour3o == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                starthour3.Text = starthour3o.ToString();
            }
            Object starthour4o = localSettings.Values["starthour4"];

            if (starthour4o == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                starthour4.Text = starthour4o.ToString();
            }
            Object starthour5o = localSettings.Values["starthour5"];

            if (starthour5o == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                starthour5.Text = starthour5o.ToString();
            }
            Object starthour6o = localSettings.Values["starthour6"];

            if (starthour6o == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                starthour6.Text = starthour6o.ToString();
            }
            Object starthour7o = localSettings.Values["starthour7"];

            if (starthour7o == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                starthour7.Text = starthour7o.ToString();
            }

            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "It is not working" how is it not working, is it throwing a error, does the values never save, does the program lock up?

Comment: This was the only documentation I could find: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx

Comment: The app runs fine, but if I enter a number (say 2) and close the app, when I reopen the app 2 is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do, first you need to explicitly save your settings for them to be persisted by calling [Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.save.aspx). Somewhere in your code you need to do `localSettings.Save()` and it should work.

2nd, if you have saved settings the first thing your code does is overwrite them with the current values of the text boxes, the whole top section where it is `localSettings.Values["Foo"] = Foo.Text` needs to be moved to the bottom.

As a side comment, do you really need to be updating your code every 10 miliseconds? That is going to eat up a TON of resources in your program. A much more normal approach is load the values at start-up then save them at shutdown.

Comment: Okay, it won't let me put localSettings.Save(). It says that save is not defined. I did #2. And for #3, this is a very early build and I'm just experimenting for now.

Comment: I just relized you are using [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer) not [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx). You are working with windows apps stuff. I don't know how to save with that.